# TensorOperations.jl Julia Package for computing contractions of tensors with vectors

Tags: vector, julia, tensor

I am trying to compute contractions of tensors with vector objects, and construct tensor objects from vectors using TensorOperations.jl. For example, I would like to compute the outer product of two simple vectors

```
using TensorOperations 
first_vec = [1 1 1] 
second_vec = [2 2 2] 
@tensor combination[a, b]:=first_vec[a]*second_vec[b]
```

Throws the following error:

```
TensorOperations.IndexError{String}("invalid permutation of length 2: (1,)")

Stacktrace:
\[1\] contract!(α::Bool, A::Matrix{Int64}, CA::Symbol, B::Matrix{Int64}, CB::Symbol, β::Bool, C::Matrix{Int64}, oindA::Tuple{Int64}, cindA::Tuple{}, oindB::Tuple{Int64}, cindB::Tuple{}, indCinoAB::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, syms::Tuple{Symbol, Symbol, Symbol})
@ TensorOperations \~/.julia/packages/TensorOperations/LDxfx/src/implementation/stridedarray.jl:247
\[2\] contract!(α::Bool, A::Matrix{Int64}, CA::Symbol, B::Matrix{Int64}, CB::Symbol, β::Bool, C::Matrix{Int64}, oindA::Tuple{Int64}, cindA::Tuple{}, oindB::Tuple{Int64}, cindB::Tuple{}, indleft::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, indright::Tuple{}, syms::Tuple{Symbol, Symbol, Symbol})
@ TensorOperations \~/.julia/packages/TensorOperations/LDxfx/src/implementation/stridedarray.jl:89
\[3\] top-level scope
@ In\[329\]:4
\[4\] eval
@ ./boot.jl:368 \[inlined\]
\[5\] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
@ Base ./loading.jl:1428\
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that:

```
first_vec = [1 1 1] 
second_vec = [2 2 2]
```

define matrices and not vectors.

```
first_vec = [1,1,1] 
second_vec = [2,2,2] 
@tensor combination[a, b]:=first_vec[a]*second_vec[b]
```

works fine.

Note the commas replacing spaces in square brackets. Spaces do `hcat` (horizontal concatenation) and it becomes a row matrix. Vectors in Julia are usually thought of as columns.